# trying to detect a string from a pair in a set

Tags: java, android

For some reason, my == operator isn't returning true when it should. I see two of the exact same strings displayed on my phone yet it's still not registering as true. Any ideas? It's a hashset of pair (string,int). getFirst returns the string in the pair.

```
private boolean contains(HashSet<Pair> mySet, String current) {
        Iterator<Pair> temp = mySet.iterator();
        String compared;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " want " +current,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        while (temp.hasNext()) {
            compared = temp.next().getFirst();


                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, compared+" "+current,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (compared==current)
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        return false;
    }
```

Comment: this question has been answered so many times now it isn't even funny

Comment: It's _a bit_ funny, in a sad way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings should not be compared with ==. In java, Strings are objects, and == will check if they are the same object reference. If you want to check if they contain the same sequence of characters, use string.equals(otherString).

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
if(compared.equals(current))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `String.equals()` method for comparing strings. As in `if (string1.equals(string2))...`.